# How can I make socketio wait before sending the next event?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I have a socket.io server which works well. It's very simple: kind of mimicking screen sharing as it broadcasts one clients position on the page to the other, who catches it and moves to said location etc. All of this works fine, but because of the way I'm catching movement, its possible (and quite common) for it to be sent too many messages at once, making it impossible for the other client to keep up.

I was wondering if there is a way to make socket.io 'sleep' or 'wait' for a certain interval, ignore the messages sent during this interval without returning an error, and then begin listening again?

It is feasible to implement this in each client (and this may be the better option), but I just wanted to know if this is possible on the server side too.

Comment: You can just do a setInterval and then broadcast whatever the current data is when the timeout expires.

Comment: Or another approach is to compare the new position and the last updated position to see if it's significant enough to send others for updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use volatile messages. If there are too much messages, they will just be dropped to go again with real time messages.

```
socket.volatile.emit('msg', data);
```

From socket.io website :

```
Sending volatile messages.
Sometimes certain messages can be dropped. Let's say you have an app that shows realtime tweets for the keyword `bieber`.

If a certain client is not ready to receive messages (because of network slowness or other issues, or because he's connected through long polling and is in the middle of a request-response cycle), if he doesn't receive ALL the tweets related to bieber your application won't suffer.

In that case, you might want to send those messages as volatile messages.
```